# Unable to retrieve item count for Sharepoint List through Microsoft Graph API

Tags: json, rest, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-list

I am currently using the Microsoft Graph API to return data in JSON for a specific list through this URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteID}/lists/{listID}/items/{itemID}
```

I would like to return data for all the items in the list by iterating through the `itemID` which is a number like 1,2,3. Although I can do that, I don't know what number to iterate to - does anyone know the API call or the URL for getting the item count in a list. If I send a GET Request to the following URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteID}/lists/{listID}/items
```

I only get back 235 list item JSON objects (much less than the 1200 that actually exist in the list) so I can't read off the last json object ID as the count.

I can do a while loop till I get an '**id doesn't exist error**' but there are some items that are being regularly deleted hence I may encounter the same error there as well.

Answer (score 0):

It can retrieve only few items when sending the API query (100-200) items. So try to use the $top query parameter

Using top query parameter. You are able to retrieve maximum 3000 items using Graph API

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteID}/lists/{listID}/items?$top=3000

Upvote if accepted as a answer